# SN74LS393N Integrated Circuit is confusing me

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, timer

Today, I was playing around with digital devices I had lying in my circuit supply box, and I picked one of my ICs, looked up it's part number, and found out that it was an SN74LS393N, a type of IC for 4 bit binary counting, it seems. I was interested to get it working, because its functionality sounded interesting, but I haven't always shined in circuitry (The datasheets and schematics tend to overwhelm me, sadly). I accessed this part's datasheet, made a circuit that I thought would work, but it does nothing, I tried changing the IC into a different one of the same model, but to no avail, so the problem is my circuit, not the chip. The datasheet only gives me data on what to provide the IC, but I just can't figure out a working circuit for it.

This is the datasheet I used:
[Dual 4-Bit Decade And Binary Counters, Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls393.pdf)

Here is an accurate schematic I made to represent the circuit I created for use with this chip.[image: Schematic]
Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Given your experience in electronics, this is actually a pretty well written question. (The Vcc resistor is a problem, as you now know. But +1 for writing something up that others could actually follow!!)

Comment: NOTES: 1. The 74LSxx series is a power hog, drawing a 1,000 times the current of CMOS. 2. The outputs can sink about 10mA, but only source about 1mA. Use low value (22 ohm) resistors with the LED's to cool things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current specification in a datasheet specifies the amount that the part draws from the power supply, not the amount of current that needs to be provided.  When the voltage at the Vcc pin is 5V, the chip will draw the amount of current that it needs, in your case 38ma to 64ma.  The current draw varies with temperature, voltage, and part to part, thus the datasheet specifies a range.

The current specifications are in the data sheet so that the designer can add up all of the currents for all of the parts in the design to determine the output current required from the power supply.  In your design, as long as the 5V power source can provide 64ma, you shouldn't have a problem.

Because of the resistor in your circuit, the voltage at the Vcc input will not be 5V due to the drop caused by the current drawn by the part.  You need to remove the resistor before the circuit can work.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer, I understand what that means now, thanks. So, should I remove this resistor and directly connect 5V to the IC, or should I raise it's resistance, so more current is given to the IC?

Comment: @AleLav: You must *remove the resistor entirely* so that the IC is free to draw whatever current it needs.

Comment: WOW, that actually fixed the problem entirely!!!!

Comment: Note that you will need a current limiting resistor for each output LED once you remove the LED from the VCC pin.  Sharing the current limiting resistor through VCC might work, but it changes the VCC at the chip depending on the number of LEDs that are turned on, so it can cause unpredictable behavior.